# Software Center crashes after fresh install (15.10)

Tags: software-center

When running the software center it briefly opens and then shutsdown. Running from terminal yields:

```
ERROR:root:DebFileApplication import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from debfile import DebFileApplication, DebFileOpenError
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/debfile.py", line 21, in <module>
    from apt.debfile import DebPackage
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/debfile.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_inst
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt_inst.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: invalid ELF header
WARNING:softwarecenter.backend.zeitgeist_logger:Support for Zeitgeist disabled
2016-02-16 15:18:57,042 - softwarecenter.backend.zeitgeist_logger - WARNING - Support for Zeitgeist disabled
INFO:softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app:setting up proxy 'None'
2016-02-16 15:18:57,073 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
WARNING:softwarecenter.backend.reviews:Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2016-02-16 15:18:57,462 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
INFO:softwarecenter.plugin:activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2016-02-16 15:18:57,463 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
INFO:softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache:aptcache.open()
2016-02-16 15:18:57,488 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:584: Warning: Source ID 70 was not found when attempting to remove it
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 183, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1378, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1316, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 150, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 193, in init_view
    SoftwarePane.init_view(self)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/softwarepane.py", line 155, in init_view
    from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.views.appdetailsview import (
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/appdetailsview.py", line 38, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.debfile import (
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/debfile.py", line 21, in <module>
    from apt.debfile import DebPackage
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/debfile.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_inst
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt_inst.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: invalid ELF header
```

Now, I was thinking of just purging python2.7 through apt-get and then reinstalling. However, this seems to also want to remove most of, well, everything else.

I tried to do:

```
sudo apt-get purge software-center
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

But the same just happens again.

Any ideas how to fix?

Thanks.